# How to avoid sorting results, returned by Index Seek?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, indexing, lookup, seek

Well, the question is not really "how to avoid" sorting as it is required by business logic, but how to do it preliminary using index, and not on the go.

I have a query plan:

```
|--Sort(TOP 5, ORDER BY:([this_].[DateAdded] DESC))
   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([this_].[Id], [Expr1002]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
        |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([storm].[dbo].[Items].[IX_Items_ByLocationSorted] AS [this_]), SEEK:([this_].[Status]=(1) AND [this_].[RegionId]=(32) AND [this_].[LocationId]=(32001)),  WHERE:([storm].[dbo].[Items].[SubcategoryTypeId] as [this_].[SubcategoryTypeId]=(88) AND ([storm].[dbo].[Items].[IsHidden] as [this_].[IsHidden]<(1) OR [storm].[dbo].[Items].[IsHidden] as [this_].[IsHidden]>(1))) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([storm].[dbo].[Items].[PK_Items] AS [this_]), SEEK:([this_].[Id]=[storm].[dbo].[Items].[Id] as [this_].[Id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
```

You can see, that Index Seek operation returns a set of rows. Than Query Optimizer does a Key Lookup to retrieve the whole row (since he'd have to return it anyway), and than it sorts all those rows by DateAdded column. It's an obvious and perfectly valid behavior. But it's really slow (might take up to 40 sec), considering the number of rows, returned by Index Seek (30k max).

How can I speed this query up and possibly avoid this on-the-go sorting?

PS: The queried table has about 3 million rows, and is frequently updated. This might cause page locking but I don't think those locks can last 40 seconds.

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM Items 
WHERE 
     SubcategoryTypeId = 88 
     and RegionId = 32
 and LocationId = 32001
 and not (IsHidden = 1 and Status = 1) 
 ORDER BY DateAdded desc
```

Comment: Sure, should've posted it in first place. I'll add it to the main post.

Comment: Why are you complaining about a sort on `DateAdded` when your **query** specifies `ORDER BY DateAdded DESC`?

Comment: The very question was not how to avoid sorting itself, but if there any way to not perform sorting on-the-go, but rely on index to store the data already sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description and how SQL Server handles indexes, no.

The sort is a necessary step, and there is no "innate" order to SQL Server data.  Indexed data **is** sorted based on the creation script for the index, but it looks like you would have a resort regardless.

As gbn rightly points out, a covering index would help your performance some but you established in the comments that you aren't interested in doing that, so you are probably at a performance plateau that you won't be able to get off of without changing a requirement or your data structure.

Comment: It is a valid point. I guess re-sorting is inevitable. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You need a [covering index](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) to remove the [key lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395275/which-is-better-bookmark-key-lookup-or-index-scan/1395322#1395322)

This will remove the intermediate sort (`ORDERED FORWARD`) which is required to match the 2 sets of data (index seek intersected with PK lookup)

Edit:

After comment: maintain a large index (define large?) or live with slow performance. You can't have fast performance with poor indexes. It is a binary choice.

Comment: I don't really want to remove this Key lookup, since the table has a lot of rows and adding all of them to Included Columns would just make an index grow huge. It could help avoid Key Lookup which is of course a good thing but the cost of maintaining this large index for this purpose only would be too high.

Comment: I would +2 if I could for comment on the binary choice :)

Comment: If I understand the mechanics of SQL Server indexes correctly, It would be exactly the same size (in rows) as the main table (even than, table contains [TEXT] fields, which can not be included in index). Also, It would cause maintainability issues in case we add new rows to the table. The index I'm using now, is covering where conditions, which is maximum I can allow for queries, which return all table rows.

Comment: @Rezgar - you can have those columns as `INCLUDE`d columns, which means they only exist at the leaf level and aren't used for looking up index values in the b-tree.  You could also just not `SELECT *` and only select the fields you need, then include those.  `SELECT *` is a pretty terrible idea on its own.

Comment: Even if the columns are INCLUDED, they are still duplicated and difficultly maintained on changes, even if not used during lookup. As to SELECT *, I pretty much agree with you on this one. But this query is generated by NHibernate and I need the returned text data (largest fields) anyway so specifying the columns manually wouldn't gain much in this specific case.

Comment: @Rezgar - An index **is a duplicated version of your data**, just narrowed and/or sorted in a different method.  If you want faster `SELECT` performance, you need indexes.  If you want faster `INSERT`s then by all means don't index, but don't expect a quick `SELECT` execution.

Comment: You're right - there should be a balance between INSERT and SELECT performance (and it's environment-specific). But this is a matter of a different question. What I was asking originally - was if it was possible for this query to avoid sorting on-the-go and store the data in the index already sorted.

Comment: Then no... there is no implicit order by in any SQL. @JNK: you should add an answer: you added a lot of info here

Comment: Thank you, guys, for your input. You're probably right - this kind of sorting can not be done using an index.

Answer (score 1):

if you'd be willing to make a partial covering index, you should be able to do something like this (note that this code is based off of a table of mine, you'd have to modify it to fit your needs):

```
    select
    b.*
from
(
    select 
        IDkey,
        row_number() over (order by Years, Months) as z
    from dbo.tblWIN_LOSS
    where Won>=10000
) a
    inner join dbo.tblWIN_LOSS b
        on a.IDkey=b.IDkey
where a.z<=5
```

i'm not 100% sure if this would give you a performance boost, but i think it should.

Edit: Ahh, you said nhibernate is returning the query, so i don't know what you can do.